# C memory management in circular string array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I am pretty new to C, and trying to create a buffer which stores the last N lines of string input in a circular array. Relevant code:

```
char ** lines;
int last_line=0;
int max_lines=0;
int max_line_length=1000;

void main()
{
    ... //set max_lines dynamically, among other setup.
    int * len = malloc(sizeof(int));
    char s[max_line_length];
    lines=malloc(sizeof(char*) * max_lines);
    while(getLine(s, len) != EOF) {
        pushLine(s, *len);
    }
}

void pushLine(char * s, int len) 
{
    //Here is where I am trying to replace the previous string in the array
    char * t = realloc(lines[last_line], sizeof(char) * len);
    memcpy(t,s,len);
    lines[last_line++]=t;
    last_line = last_line % max_lines;
}
```

If I replace `realloc()` with `malloc()`, this works perfectly, but that would create a memory leak. When I use `realloc()`, it works fine for awhile, but then I notice that program locations seem to get randomly overwritten.

Any thoughts around what could be causing those errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `MAX_LINES` really zero?!?!?!?

Comment: No, it is set dynamically at runtime, but I skipped that code since I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: Presumably `len` in `main()` scope is an `int *` - is it always pointing to the correct place? Does `realloc()` ever return `NULL`?

Comment: added the declaration code around len, thanks!

Comment: @user26324 A major convention in C programming is to use all caps names (Like `MAX_LINES`) to indicate constants that are specified by #defines.  So your naming and saying it was generated dynamically threw me for a bit.

Comment: Peter, great point, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @PeterM I did some tests around len - seems to always be correct within the pushLine function.

Comment: Does your `len` count the null byte that terminates strings? It isn't clear, but if it doesn't, you don't have null terminated strings in your data structure, which is bad news.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Bingo, what a foolish mistake. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `malloc()` before doing the `realloc()`.  `realloc()` changes the already allocated memory.  You should init the `lines` memory area to `NULL` first and then `realloc()` will perform a `malloc()` the first time since `realloc()` will operate like `malloc()` if the pointer is `NULL`.

See this [writeup on realloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/).

So add a line after the `malloc()` to initialize the area to null or use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

See this [writeup on calloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/).

Comment: Thanks @RichardChambers, I switched it over to calloc, but this was actually the result of not counting the string terminator in the length.

Comment: @Sid, from what I could tell you had several problems with the realloc() being the main one.  Len plus one for the zero terminator is a problem that most people run into and something easy to forget.  Another problem is the memcpy() which uses a len that does not include the zero terminator on the string.  Also the use of memcpy() assumes byte sized characters.  The use of malloc() for the integer len does not really make sense.  Better to just use a stack variable instead.  It looks you really should keep up with the first line as well as the last line since it is a circular buffer.